# How does LINQ to SQL build queries?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, lambda

I experimented with LINQ to SQL and tracked the actual SQL that was executed on my local SQL Server Express instance using the SQL Server Profiler. I noticed that LINQ to SQL is able to convert some faily complex, non-straightforward C# queries into SQL. Examples:

```
var x = People.Where(p => new string[] { "Smith", "Miller" }.Contains(p.LastName));
```

gets translated into

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName] FROM [dbo].[People] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[LastName] IN (@p0, @p1)',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Smith',@p1=N'Miller'
```

which essentially equates to

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName]
FROM [dbo].[People] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[LastName] IN ('Smith', 'Miller')
```

Equally impressive:

```
var z = People.Where(p => p.LastName[0] == 'H');
```

becomes

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName] FROM [dbo].[People] AS [t0] WHERE UNICODE(CONVERT(NChar(1),SUBSTRING([t0].[LastName], @p0 + 1, 1))) = @p1',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=0,@p1=72
```

i.e.

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName]
FROM [dbo].[People] AS [t0]
WHERE UNICODE(CONVERT(NChar(1),SUBSTRING([t0].[LastName], 1, 1))) = 72
```

How are these nonobvious queries constructed? Is there a complete list of all such operations that are supported?

Comment: They are constructed based on Expression Tree that compiler generates for your lambda expression passed to `Where` method. I don't know if there is a list of constructs that are supported.

Comment: Technically your code uses Lambda methods.  The compiler translates Lambda methods into Linq, then at run time the Linq statements are translated into TSQL.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Isn't it the other way round? LINQ query snytax is translated to lambda syntax?

Comment: Read this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Comment: @ArindamNayak this document does not appear to provide a list of mappings from C# methods to SQL statements.

Comment: If you know SQL , then definitely you can make a list of operations supported by LINQ, and if it can't be done with LINQ, come up with that as question.

Comment: I remember being equally impressed when I first found out about this.

Answer (score 1):

Note: provided as an answer, because it would not fit into the comments:

Linq to [x] (SQL, XML, ...) is based on a LINQ provider implementation that supports a set of domain/application specific operations (e.g. those specific to SQL). The LINQ provider builds an expression tree of these supported operations, and provides the means to translate these into SQL statements using expression visitors. Creating a LINQ provider for (a subset of) SQL, or any other domain that isn't small, is quite involved and complex.

Very good introductory information used to be available from Bart De Smet, more specifically his blog on blogs.bartdesmet.net with e.g. the MinLINQ article. However this blog seems to be gone now. Some videos of him explaining these things are still available online, e.g. https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Erik-Meijer-and-Bart-De-Smet-LINQ-to-Anything.

You could check out https://github.com/re-motion/Relinq for a very advanced provider, or search for "LINQ provider" for more information.